# find files with spaces modified in last 60 days and tar.gz in files no bigger then 4gb with date

Tags: find, tar, 7-zip

I maintain a file server.
I need to backup files that have changed in a period of time.

First i compressed up everything to 4gb files and backed up to dvd. But 7z that I was using

```
7z a -t7z /home/user/myfiles051413_proj.7z /home/share/projects -v4000m -m0=bzip2 -mmt=4
```

does not seem to have a way to zip modified files in the last 60 days and i am unsure how to pass that to a command sorta like this. I do not want to have to compress the whole folder and backup what is already backed up! (waste of space)

tar seems to work good with this

```
find /home/share/projects -mtime -60
```

and  piping it into a command works too but spaces give me issues. Here is the command I am attempting to get work.  Finding all files modified in last 60 days. then compressing them into 4gb files.

```
find /home/share/projects/ -mtime -60 | xargs tar -cvML 4194304 -f /home/user/myfiles`date '+%d%m%Y'_proj.tar`
```

at the moment it will run for a while then only have one small file in it. it prints out numerous files on the screen!

---

I have been playing with -print0

```
find /home/samba/shares/projects -mtime -60 -type f -print0| xargs tar -cvML 4194304 -f /home/samba/shares/bkup/`date '+%d%m%Y'_proj.tar` -T - --null
```

i get a whole lot of 
tar: de: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Comment: To get around problems with spaces use the `-print0` option in find. (and match xargs with -0).

Comment: You're missing the `-0` option to `xargs`. Also, if you want to add information, *edit* your question. This isn't a discussion forum. If you're going to add an answer, we expect it to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you have bug in last script with -print0 .

1. you use xargs . not good idea because for lot of files xargs run tar twice or more.
2. you use for tar -T -  option. rights, but what for in this situation is xargs ?

simply remove xargs because it is unneeded. this grab all files from stdin and put to tar as arguments at the end. then tar -T option gets nothing on his stdin .